# Matplotlib overlaying multiple images with different colors

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, colors

I have a list (image_list) with images in the forms of numpy arrays. I want to overlay all of these images into 1 single image, and I want each image to have its own color.

Attached is a screenshot showing some of the individual images; i want each of the "curves" (gray stuff) to be a different color, not the actual background itself. This way when I overlay all the images the colors will help me identify each specific image.  [individual images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNM5H.png)

Attached is a screenshot of what I tried. Additionally, to clarify, by "overlay" I mean I want all the images in ONE single image, not multiple plots. Thus, I don't think changing cmap will work because that also changes the background color; I only want the color of the actual "data"/image to change.

Any help would be appreciated. [what i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9ddJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

If your images are just binary data (zeros and ones) then you could change the data in each subsequent image by one count. Then you plot them all in the same image and matplotlib will take care of the coloring. You could also merge them into a single array first with the same result

1st image: zeros and ones

2nd image: zeros and 2s

3rd image: zeros and 3s
....

in pseudo code:

```
new_image_list = []
for idx, img in enumerate(img_list):
    img = np.where(img > threshold, 1, 0)
    img *= (idx+1)
    new_image_list.append(img)
for img in new_image_list:
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not  just 0's and 1's. Here's an example of what it looks like: https://imgur.com/a/EnFW2N8.

Comment: That's a float matrix. This 0.1-value is you background? Then apply a threshold first to binaries the image first. Then my answer will work again. I have put in the optional step. Otherwise make the value difference between the images so big that the automatic color scaling separates them.

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct. 0.1 is for the background, 1.0 is for the actual image values. Can you elaborate what you mean by "value difference between the images"? Do you mean changing the 1.0's to like 1.0, 100.0, 1000.0 for different images?

Comment: Exactly. You have to make sure that the values of interest do not overlap in the images. Your suggestions (1.0, 100, 1000, ...) would do the trick. But any others will too.